# What is a "violator"?

Tags: audio, video, terminology

I'm exchanging email about specs with a video editor who was going to send me materials. He asked me if I needed a "violator" in the video to do my audio work?

What is a violator? Is it a video term for pop syncs?

PS> Tried to Google but different unrelated things come up.

Comment: Might it be possible that it is a typo?

Comment: Violator is not a term I know. Perhaps he meant validator?

Answer (score 1):

Asked an editor friend of mine and said it's probably sync tones (not just pops) which some production outfits use instead of a pop when a video fades from black (aka first frame is a black frame). The end of a tone is the first frame.

They do this because some amateur audio guys still don't know how 2 pops work and end up starting the audio immediately after the pop. (Because they were instructed that video starts from black.)